# Wrong NavigationBar position after modal dialog was shown while StatusBar is in "in call" mode

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

In my [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) driven app, I use a modal view to display some views. Inside this modal view controller, I also use [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker) to show a image picker. The problem: When the second modal dialog is shown while the "in call" status bar is also displayed, the navigation bar position of the first modal dialog will be under the in call status bar. Here is an example (I toggle the "in call" mode in the iOS simulator using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>):

[image: Example gif]

I tried to call `forceUpdate` in a very first component that contains all the screens when the height of the status bar changes but this does not fix the issue. Is there a better (or even known?) way to get rid of this?

Comment: There is a package on npm called react-native-call-detection. You can use a custom component as your header and using call events set a padding value to solve this issue.

Comment: @htkibar Unfortunately this would be a very hacky workaround for a issue that should be solved in iOS/RN and it would be very hard to track the view state to determine whether the navigation bar is drawn in an incorrect way.

Comment: Yes. Just wanted to point out a way to solve the issue for now. Also, if rerendering solves the problem a potential way to solve it should be forceUpdating after a set amount of time, albeit still hacky.

Comment: Called `forceUpdate` every 1000ms on the very upper component - unfortunately with no effect at all. Think is issue is above the react native layer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are actually hitting this RN bug or similar: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/972

The "solution" will be hacky like you said but this seems like the normal thing for RN apps.